# Use a directive to share an object between controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="location" ng-controller="locationController">...</div>
<div id="markerTypes" ng-controller="filterController">...</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Where the map is a google map, that I create in a factory:

```
(function (app) {
    'use strict';
    app.factory('emap', function () {
        var center = { lat: 48.2, lng: 2.3 }; 
        var opts = { center: center, zoom: 4 };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmaps'), opts);  
        return map;    
    });

    app.controller('locationController',['$scope', 'emap', 
        function ($scope, emap) {
            // using shared emap
        }]);

    app.controller('filterController',['$scope', 'emap', 
        function ($scope, emap) {
            // using shared emap
        }]);

})(angular.module('mapApp', []));
```

As I understood there are mainly **two** methods to share the map:

- via a `service` (factory as readonly service, like I did) or
- via the `$rootScope`

However, in order to manipulate the DOM (say I do it with the map), the AngularJS documentation [recommends](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) using directives

> Do **not** use controllers to:
>
> - Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects
>     its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and
>     ***[directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)*** to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

Could I use the directives in this case to share the map between controllers? by eg:

```
<div my-map id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A directive should not hold a data model. Use services or factories for this